# Genealogy plugin in elgg

Tags: php, elgg

so I am trying to create a website using the open source website

```
elgg
```

but when I try to enable the plugin Genealogy I got this error shown in the picture

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Elgg 2.0 or more.
I think the plugin you trying to use is this one : https://elgg.org/plugins/384792 and this plugin has't been updated in over 6 years !

You can add [a manifest](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/guides/plugins.html#manifest-xml) in this plugin and try it, but I'm not sure it will work with elgg 2.0...